# installing opencsv in eclipse + where is the documentation

Tags: java, eclipse, opencsv

I'm not sure how I can get openCSV working in Eclipse.

I've tried downloading the latest version (3.8) and only got a .jar. Similarly I downloaded 2.3 and a .gz archive. What do?

Once we get that sorted out, where is the documentation for using opencsv? It's one thing to get the plugin installed, but I have no idea how to actually use it to read a CSV file, ignore values, enter the values into an array, etc.

Comment: Why did you download an older version? What about adding the JAR file do you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use any jar, place the file in the project and add the file to the build path of the project. You will then be able to use the classes from the library.

[image]

You can find the api documentation here

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/

Example usage are provided in following page

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Now you've confused me even more

Comment: Copy the jar into your project and add it to the build path as shown above.

Comment: How to integrated openCSV inside web application?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing to me.  OpenCSV is a library you import into your java programs either by adding it to your classpath as suggested by Sarit or by adding it as an dependency in the pom.xml file of the project you are working on - which an example is shown at http://opencsv.sourceforge.net

It is not an eclipse plugin so there is no "installation" process.